# ActionScript 3.0 flex SWF metadata width and height

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash, papervision3d

I have an actionscript, which makes a dynamic image wall. It gets parameters from FlashVar and changes the width and height dynamically.

When I use

```
[SWF(width="584",height="290")]
```

It's fully centered, but when I remove it, it's appear ~+50px from left.
How can I set dynamically the SWF metadata or what I need to set for the correct view?

Top of the picture with SWF tag and the bottom is without SWF tag.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bbb4426bf0.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bbb4426bf0.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
stage.align = "TL";
```